# AudioSessionProperty on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application I need to enable loud speaker and enable bluetooth.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                             sizeof (audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);

    UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;

    AudioSessionSetProperty (
                             kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
                             sizeof (allowBluetoothInput),
                             &allowBluetoothInput
                             );
```

But it is not working together. I mean that if bluetooth is on I hear voice from BT headset, if it is off, I hear voice not from loud speaker.  How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `changeDefaultRoute` instead of `audioRouteOverride` for the speaker?

```
UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(
                       kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker
                     , sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute)
                     , &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```

This fixes the output going to speaker instead of receiver issue, but I cannot test the bluetooth input side (no bluetooth device!). It may *not* as from what I can gather `OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput` actually controls input *and* output.

Apple says this:

> This property affects the kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord category as follows: If the audio input to the device is coming from a Bluetooth headset, setting this property to TRUE results in audio output also going to the Bluetooth headset.
>   ([*Audio Session Services Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html))

In general, Apple do not want apps to manipulate routing in ways that may be counter-intuitive to the user. The idea is that routing should be something that the user feels they have control over.