# Can't control the Speaker on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, avaudiosession

I have followed method that takes care about my speaker state:

**AudioSession.h**

```
enum {
    kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None    = 0,
    kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker = 'spkr'
};
```

**MyClass**

```
@synthesize speakerEnabled;

...

- (void)setSpeakerEnabled:(BOOL)enable {
speakerEnabled = enable;
if(enable) {
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;  
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute
                             , sizeof (audioRouteOverride)
                             , &audioRouteOverride);
 } else {
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;  
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute
                             , sizeof (audioRouteOverride)
                             , &audioRouteOverride);
 }
}
```

However **it works on iPhone only**, for iPad - nothing happens.

- When I press on button: `Speaker On`, I enter to `if(enable)` and `AudioSessionSetProperty` receives `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker`;
- When I press on button: `Speaker Off`, I enter to `else` and `AudioSessionSetProperty` receives `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None`;

I started to debug and din't find difference between to devices.

*I have iPad2 iOS 6.1.*

Did I miss something?

please, help me

**Edit**

As LombaX says I added on launch application `AVAudioSession` category:

```
NSError *err = nil;
    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&err];

    if(!success){
        [MyLogger logc:MyLoggerLog format:"%@",[err localizedDescription]];
    }
```

`success = YES`

Still doesn't work.

Comment: `AudioSessionSetProperty` has a return value, did you check it?

Comment: Yes, returns `OSStatus=0` only

Comment: What is the return value of the setCategory call? And, if it's NO, the relative error

Comment: `setCategory` returns `YES`, no errors

Comment: "nothing happens" ... do you mean - speaker is always enabled? or...?

Comment: @HeWas means I press on button: On/Off and enter to `if(enable)` and `else` respectively. So `AudioSessionSetProperty` receives 2 states: if enable -`kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker`; if disable - `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None`. Thanks

Comment: @MaximShoustin, take a look at my answer, I have made assumptions of what you are trying to do, apologies if I assumed wrongly!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the use of this property. You are hoping to enable/disable your speaker. That is not quite the intent of `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute`. Rather, it affects the output sound *routing*, in a fairly limited manner.

These are the various possible output routes avaiable to the iPhone

```
extern const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_LineOut           
extern const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_Headphones            
extern const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BluetoothHFP        
extern const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BluetoothA2DP      
extern const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInReceiver   
extern const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInSpeaker    
extern const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_USBAudio            
extern const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_HDMI              
extern const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_AirPlay
```

These are only *possible* routes  - what is actually available is context-dependent. Apple severely restricts your ability to determine these routes in-app as it is something that the user needs to control in a device-consistent manner. Most of them are determined implicitly by the user plugging/unplugging hardware (headphone, USB, HDMI, line out), and Apple doesn't  want your app to mess with user expectations here.

Airplay can be selected using `MPVolumeView`'s  `routeButton` if the media context is correct (and airplay is available). Bluetooth can be guided by `OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput` ([which controls both input *and* output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189685/audiosessionproperty-on-iphone/16194895#16194895))

IN particular, note that `kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInReceiver` is the low-level speaker on the iPhone you hold to your ear when making a phone call. This is the  default audio output route for the iPhone if an external device (eg headphones) is not plugged in. `kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInSpeaker` is the 'handsfree' louder speaker at the bottom of the phone.

You can reroute from whatever the current default is to this `BuiltInSpeaker` by setting one of these override properties:

```
key: kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute
values:   kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker
      :   kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None
```

> Specifies whether or not to override the audio session category’s normal audio route.

```
key: kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker
values:   TRUE
      :   FALSE
```

> Specifies whether or not to route audio to the speaker (instead of to the receiver) when no other audio route, such as a headset, is connected.

Both of these are only designed to be used with the `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` Audio Session category.

Notice that in both cases you are not choosing amongst any output route, you are only overriding the "default route" in favour of the built-in (loud)speaker.

The iPad, lacking a phone, does not have a `BuiltInReceiver` type of speaker. It's default route, in the absence of connected gadgets or airplay, is that very same `BuiltInSpeaker`. Therefore, overriding doesn't have any effect.

Assuming you are really trying to mute the audio in your app, how you achieve that depends on many other aspects of your app design. If you want to mute the *device*, Apple would rather the user controls this via the ring/silent switch. It seems they wouldn't have it any other way:

> I've had a response from Apple on this.
>   They've said they don't and never have provided a method for detecting hardware mute switch and don't intend to do so.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8009073/1375695

"*The speaker setting is an overide for the device, not for a given sound*"
http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Mar/msg00300.html

Comment: Thanks for "clear" my mind. Im not iOS guru :) and your description is clear. Anyways if this way doesn't work on iPad can I use workaround to, at least, mute Speaker like set Volume 0 and vice versa 100% on click on?

Comment: @MaximShoustin, it depends on your design - for example if using AVAudioPlayer you can set  the `volume` property  to 0

Comment: I use SIP protocol and show video/audio from other device (x264 codec)

Comment: @MaximShoustin then you will need to give many more details of your app design eg what libraries / frameworks are you using?. Under what user / app / device conditions do you want to mute the sound? You should really be opening a new question to do that or we will deviate from your original question too far (u can link to it here).

Comment: on iPhone above mentioned snippets of code work fine: mute on/off. On iPad in debug mode I run the same flow and nothing happens. Right now im not on xCode and can't give you more info what I use so far

Comment: @MaximShoustin, please don't call it mute on/off, that is not what is happening, you are changing the audio output route between  highpower handsfree speaker and low-power telephone receiver speaker . You didn't mute, you just cannot hear it so well as it is much quieter on receiver speaker (you need to hold your ear to the phone to hear that one). IPad doesn't have a receiver speaker, it's default output is (already) the highpower speaker.

Comment: I have no clue how to mute highpower speaker, or set 0 volume. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29247/discussion-between-he-was-and-maxim-shoustin)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set the audio category before playing?
I remember I had the same problem a while ago, and found this solution (adjust the category)

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

I didn't found anything on the documentation, I think that on iPad you must set the category because iPhone and iPad differs about a detail: on iPhone, the left hardware switch can mute the speaker. On iPad, the same switch is used to lock the rotation.

Try and let me know

EDIT:

useful link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html